# How do I join different values of FK in the same column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

As straightforward as I can make:

What I have...

```
Table users:
user_id | user_name 
   1    |   Jack  
   2    |   Chuck   


Table jobs:
job_id |   job_name 
   1   |    Farmer
   2   |    Ninja
   3   |    Teacher
```

What I wish I could do using just a JOIN...

```
user_id | user_name | user_role
   1    |   Jack    |   1, 2
   2    |   Chuck   |   2, 3
```

What I really really want...

```
user_id | user_name |     user_role
   1    |   Jack    |   Farmer, Ninja
   2    |   Chuck   |   Ninja, Teacher
```

So, how should I do this? By the way I'm using knexjs, but with a SQL explanation I could do the rest by myself.

Comment: How do you know the mapping between users and jobs?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you are missing a junction table which relates users to their jobs:

```
user_jobs

user_id | job_id
1       | 1
1       | 2
2       | 2
2       | 3
```

With this table being defined, we only need a series of joins:

```
SELECT
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name,
    STRING_AGG(j.job_name, ',' ORDER BY j.job_id) user_role
FROM users u
INNER JOIN user_jobs uj
    ON u.user_id = uj.user_id
INNER JOIN jobs j
    ON uj.job_id = j.job_id
GROUP BY
    u.user_id,
    u.user_name;
```